# Weird rendered lighting, probably bad topology

Tags: rendering, mesh, light

This is one of my first models, an adjustable wrench. Both Eevee and Cycles produce similar results, which look kinda weird. Adding bevels around the wormscrew hole helped a bit, but now I'm stuck.

[image: Blender screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like to me you applied smooth shading to the object, but haven't turned on auto-smooth.

Try going into the Properties window -> Object data properties -> Normals -> and check Auto Smooth.

Then fiddle around with the degree slider until all your curved surfaces are smooth, but the flat areas don't have this lighting error. I think the default 30° should work fine in this case.

Comment: And that fixed it, thank you so much! But will it render the same strange way if I try to export the mesh as is to a game engine (learning Unreal too atm)?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know that. But I suppose it should have a similar option somewhere, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: I don't think (I'm quite sure) Unreal or a different game engine (Unity for example) will use the smoothing options or auto smooth settings from Blender.